# f# get product of 4 adjacent numbers in an array

Tags: .net, f#

I'm trying to get the max product of 4 adjacent numbers in an array
this is what I got now:

```
let max4 line =
    let rec loop acc = function
        |a :: b :: c :: [] -> acc
        |a :: b :: c :: d :: tl -> loop (max(acc, a*b*c*d)) tl
        |_ -> 0
    loop 0 line
```

I get a compilation error on the `max(,)` saying:

> error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
>       'a     but given a
>       'a * 'b -> 'a * 'b     The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''a * 'b -> 'a * 'b'

---

Anybody knows what's wrong in this code ? (or another solution)

Comment: Array or list? Your question says array, but your code is using lists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the input is a list of integers:

```
let max4 line =
    let rec loop acc = function
        | x1::(x2::x3::x4::_ as xs) -> loop (max acc (x1*x2*x3*x4)) xs
        |_ -> acc
    loop System.Int32.MinValue line
```

You made some mistakes:

- The built-in `max` function is in the curry form `max: 'a -> 'a -> 'a`.
- The next case to address in your function should be `b::c::d::tl`, not `tl` only.
- The product could be negative, so `0` is not a good starting point. Beware that integer overflow could happen (which I still haven't addressed in my function).

Comment: got it, the problem was me using `(a,b)` instead of `a b` also missed b::c::d at the end

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to using explicit recursion, you could also solve this using existing F# library functions. This is how most F# data processing is written, but it is always good to learn how to write recursive functions by hand (because you sometimes need them).

So, just for completeness, here is a way to solve the probelm more declaratively using existing functions:

```
let max4 line = 
  line |> Seq.windowed 4 
       |> Seq.map (Seq.reduce (*))
       |> Seq.max
```

The first line turns the list into a sequence of 4-element arrays (windows). This is then passed to `Seq.map` that turns the window into a product of the elements. To do that, I'm using `Seq.reduce` which reduces sequence (window, in this case) using the specified function, here the `(*)` operator. Finally, to find the maximal element of the products, you can use `Seq.max` function.

Comment: `Seq.windowed` returns _sliding_ windows; the code in his question uses contiguous groups.

Comment: @Daniel : The selected answer also uses sliding windows, so I guess that's what the OP really wanted after all.

Comment: @ildjarn: Perhaps...or maybe he didn't notice.

Comment: Well, skipping all except the fourth element could be done using `Seq.mapi` followed by `Seq.filter`.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the other answers sum sliding windows but in your question they're contiguous. If you want the latter you can define such a function:

```
let groupsOf n items =
  if n <= 0 then invalidArg "n" "must be greater than zero"
  if List.isEmpty items then invalidArg "items" "empty list"
  let rec loop i acc items =
    seq {
      match i, items with
      | 0, [] -> yield List.rev acc
      | _, [] -> ()
      | 0, _ ->
        yield List.rev acc
        yield! loop n [] items
      | _, x::xs -> yield! loop (i - 1) (x::acc) xs
    }
  loop n [] items
```

then use code similar to Tomas':

```
let max4 line = 
  line |> groupsOf 4 
       |> Seq.map (Seq.reduce (*))
       |> Seq.max
```

`groupsOf` ignores any partial group at the end (as does your code).

Comment: I don't really know what's contigous vs sliding, so I'll show what I'm doing, this: http://projecteuler.net/problem=11 , so this function is a part or the solution for problem 11 on euler

Comment: @ChuckNorris : Given `[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8]`, what do you want to follow `[1;2;3;4]`: `[2;3;4;5]` or `[5;6;7;8]`? The other answers give the former, this (and your question) gives the latter.

Comment: all possible 4 adjacent numbers in the list: 1234, 2345, 3456 ... 5678

Comment: @ChuckNorris : That would be _sliding_ then. ;-]